# Chrome System Print Dialog Text White Highlight

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing

I'm having an issue in Google Chrome on Windows only (tried IE11, FF, Opera, Safari) with printing. The issue only occurs when using the **system** print dialog. Using the Chrome Print Preview renders expected results, but it's just when using the system print dialog that I get the issue.

The first image below is the expected result (printed using the normal Chrome Print Preview window):
[image: Expected printout result]

And this one is what I get (using the system print dialog):
[image: Actual result]

I think it's pretty self explanatory what the issue is - all the text has a white highlight.

The other possibly related issue is that none of my fonts are correct - the PDF is rendering using Arial, instead of the correct fonts I've declared.

These were printed to a PDF printer, however the results are exactly the same when printed on paper, and I've tried two different manufacturers of printers.

I would post CSS (as I suspect that's the issue) but I'm not really sure what to post.

I've tried changing heaps of different CSS values from various elements (too many to name), but I've tried the obvious ones: background-colors and backgrounds, tried removing opacities etc.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** A live URL with an example is at: [iNewsletter](http://www1.goinewsletter.com/post/521)

**Edit:** Just wrote a simple test case which also fails:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #bg {width: 500px; height: 500px;}
            #text {margin-top: -500px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="bg"><img src="http://inws-cache-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/3-resize-1024-768.jpg" width="500" height="500" /></div>
        <div id="text">This text will have a white highlight</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Which leads me to think it's a Chrome bug

Comment: Do you have a live url for us to test?

Comment: Sure do! I updated the question to include this.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am running into the same exact issue.

Comment: @Rabbi I haven't had any progress with this, I've just encouraged users to not use the system print dialog. I also opened a bug report with Chromium a while back: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=322519&can=4&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: I have one client who needs to use the system print dialog. They need to print on legal size paper, and that cannot be done from the chrome dialog. So now I have a catch 22. Either they print on 11" paper or they print on the 14" that they need and then chrome puts these white backgrounds that interferes with borders and can even block out other text.

Comment: Does the site work in any other browser? Because it seems to only happen in Chrome on Windows; FF, Safari, IE and Chrome on OS X seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your CSS like you guessed. Search for @media print in your CSS, that controls the printing style. The live site you provided, doesn't allow any print at all so you get a totally white document as it sets the print style display:none.

Comment: Can you elaborate? It prints as I expect it to using Chrome Print Preview, so the `@media print` is working correctly in that regard.

Comment: The live site does not reproduce your problem on my system, so it's hard to say. It either prints perfect or doesn't let me to preview at all.

Comment: Can you try clicking the 'Print using system dialog' button in Chrome to see if you get the white highlight issue I'm having?

Comment: Okay, I can now reproduce your problem. It happens to all system default printing dialogue, no matter Chrome or FF, so I'm pretty sure it's caused by the "@"media print. The transparent background and opacity attribute is causing the problem. If you just try removing the whole "@"media print part, that should work for you.

Comment: Yeah I've already tried removing the `@media print` section of the CSS with no luck. I tried this on a Mac and it prints as expected so it appears to be a Windows issue

Comment: I guess that's because you still have transparent background image for normal css, try set those background in '@'media print to none and remove all transparent/opacy and see what happens. Got to do with the css that's for sure.

Comment: You were right, it is a bug, a known one but new, see here https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=177651. 
On the other hand, someone has the same issue as you on Stackoverflow and he found it working on some other PCs, he thought it was driver issue but I believe it was the Chrome version that was older as stated in Google Forum.